# Updating a big table using UpdateRow cursor and grouping by values from a cell

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor

I'm working with a big table in ArcGIS Pro, with data based on cells and date, to estimate population values at the end of different days. For that, I use official population data on the first day, but from the second day, the initial population is the final population value obtained in the first day.

An example:

| Cell | Date | Initial_Population | Lose_Population | Win_Population | Final_Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Madrid | 1 | 50000 | 1000 | 2000 | 51000 |
| Madrid | 2 | 51000 | 3000 | 5000 | 59000 |
| Madrid | 3 | 59000 | 4000 | 1000 | 56000 |
| Barcelona | 1 | 40000 | 5000 | 1000 | 36000 |
| Barcelona | 2 | 36000 | 2000 | 4000 | 38000 |
| Barcelona | 3 | 38000 | 1000 | 4000 | 41000 |

For that, I'm trying to use a Python code, in particular an `UpdateCursor`. The problem is that I'm not very skillful on Python, so I don't know how to create loops using the cell values (there are +3200 cells in total), and then updating by the day order.

```
##row [0] = cell##
##row [1] = order##
##row [2] = initial_population##
##row [3] = lose_population##
##row [4] = win_population##
##row [5] = mobile_population---- pob_inicio - pob_perdida + pob_ganancia##
##row [6] = final_population---- (mobile_population* 100) / 82.5##
import arcpy

fc = "tabla_test"
fields = ["cell", "order", "initial_population", "lose_population", "win_population", "mobile_population", "final_population"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    cntr = 1
    #calculate final_population of a row -> ((initial_population - lose_population + win_population)*100)/82.5
    for row in cursor:
        #calculate final_population in day 1 using the official population
        if row[1] == 1:
            row[5] = row[2] - row[3] + row[4]
            row[6] = (row[5] * 100) / 82.5
        formerRow = row
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I'm adding two pictures to show the data I'm using and to show more clearly the cell and order rows I want to use to group, order and update data.

[image: Table orderer by cells to show the different dates (fecha) and order numbers it has]
[image: Table orderer by date to show the different cell values it has]

Comment: I'm not allowed to share the data. The most I can do is to show screens with some rows of the data and to provide some information of it (the table has 479178 rows. It includes 3214 spatial cells and 149 days).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].Tossing a huge try/except block around code isn't the best way to debug code. This is especially true for GIS SE questions, where we not only need to know the task, but what error you have encountered. We're really not a Learn to Code site, nor a Code This For Me site. The code you've presented should give a clear Python error (assignment instead of equivalence in the `if`). In database terms, "big" and "large" have special meanings, so starting with "big" then revealing this to be only a few thousand cells could reduce interest.

Comment: if row[1] = 1: does not look like correct as a first observation. Try ==. My main comment is that you would be better off by using field calculator rather than the update cursor since it is a relatively simple calculation.

Comment: I agree with @fatih_dur that `if row[1] = 1:` should be `if row[1] == 1:`. But your logic is flawed as if row[1] equals date 2 or 3 it goes into the else section of your code and the first line is to set `row[2] = row[6]`  but row[6] has yet to be set for that row. You are wanting the value in row[6] from date 1. You need to adapt your code to remember what row[6] was from date 1 for the current cell. Then dates 2 and 3, 4, 5...

Comment: The `Final_population` field is what you're trying to calculate?

Comment: Thank you very much. Final_population and Initial_population are the fields I'm trying to calculate based on the date, and by cells. Every day must have a final, updated population that is the initial population of the next day, and every cell has an initial population. Considering is a total of 479178 rows, the dates and the days, I can't use a Field Calculator to go separately, so an Updatecursor would be a more efficient, direct option. I'm swapping the = for == in the first if interaction. As @Hornbydd said, I have to adapt the code to make row[6] remember being from date 1 of the cell.

Comment: I have edited the code removing the try-except block, swapping the = for ==, and adding the formerRow = row. This solves the main issue of making the initial population row having the value of the final population of the previous row. The problem is that it affects the entire table, and I want to cut the loop for every value in the cell row. My idea is to create a dictionary with all the values in that cell row, and associate them to the order row (so the initial_population of 1B cell in its day 1 won't be the final population of 1A cell in its final day).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the _starting_ situation of your table. Am I correct in saying at the start of processing only rows that are date 1 for a cell have an initial population value, so dates 2,3 4... are Null values? ALL rows have a win and lose value and ALL final population rows have Null values as they are to be computed?